# setHomePage IE no prompt

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm using this script to set my site has home page on IE (I know it is not possible on FF and CH):

```
if (document.all) { 
  document.body.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)'; 
  document.body.setHomePage('myurl'); 
}
```

But this function shows always a confirmation prompt.

Is possible to `setHomePage` without showing the prompt?

Comment: No and why on earth would you want to?

Comment: This would be a huge security problem - and Microsoft hates those.

Comment: No, because my browser belongs to _me_,  not you. BTW you could probably do something with ActiveX if you can convince the poor hapless soul to run it. That's why I don't allow my wife to use IE :-) I assume CH is Chrome, yes? I've not seen it called that before.

Comment: I just want to confirm my boss that is not possible. We know that is possible from our toolbar. Our problem are the users that we have, they are very newbies.

Comment: Hmm, while I don't like the _idea_ behind the question, I do still think the question itself is useful (even if only to indicate that it's not a good idea). In other words, I disagree with the downvote, so I'm countering it.

Comment: I think a confirmation box can't be a problem for any person above the age of 6... I mean it's basically a Yes or No question. Srsly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

I personally fixed several bugs in IE6 the allowed people to abuse the homepage prompt.

It is 100% by-design that you cannot change the user's homepage without their knowledge and consent.